# In "BankID" on Windows, where exactly is the certificate/ID file stored?

Tags: windows, security, backup

Today, I finally caved in and went through the ordeal to install this "BankID" thing on my machine. I don't want it on my system, but without it, it's impossible to do anything anymore in Sweden, such as placing a bid on a house.

They have three options: "Mobile" (meaning a "smartphone" with an app, which I don't have), a physical card (which is apparently even more of a chore to get), and finally "BankID on computer file", which is what I had to pick.

Basically, they make you install this "security program" which manages your "BankIDs" on the Windows machine. It appears to have set up itself from clicking a `bankid://` link, most likely containing some kind of id which it fetched over the network inside the application.

Anyway, the point is that I have it working, but I can't figure out where it actually stores that "encrypted id file" on my machine.

I've looked through the (rather minimal) GUI program and the closest thing to a "Backup file" feature is "Search path to log", which displays: `C:/Users/John Doe/AppData/Roaming/BankID/Logs`

Going to that path, one dir up, shows me a dir called "IDs". It contains only one file: `0.ngp`.

I've searched for ".ngp" but nowhere online does it mention that this is anything but some game console file format. It appears to be binary when I try opening it in a text editor.

Is this file what they expect me to figure out to back up? Did they just assume that nobody was going to do this and so they didn't bother to even make it clear that this is the important file to keep backed up and restore whenever I move to a new machine/installation of Windows?

I couldn't find any mention of this in their FAQ on their website.

For something which repeatedly makes a specific point about me using an "ENCRYPTED FILE" (it's even in the title of the product) on my PC, they certainly don't seem to encourage me to back it up. It seems of utmost importance that this doesn't get lost, but they make me guess as to how to back it up?

Comment: You might have it in your certificate store, located in Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Content -> Certificates

Comment: @LPChip Can't find it there, but even so, I want to back up actual files on the file system?

Comment: If the certificate were in your certificate store, you would export the backup from there. Whatever you install just isn't always going to be a file. It can be something being installed into a database in a way to protect it from being tampered with.

Comment: Even if this so sensitive file exists, it will be encrypted and probably hard-wired to your computer hardware in a similar way to Microsoft's Digital Entitlement. I think you should concentrate on backing up the computer, rather than the key, preferably with the occasional image backup of the disk (and not with Windows Backup).